# Validating TextBox input as you type in 8.1 universal app

Tags: data-binding, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm building a universal app for windows 8.1 and windows phone 8.1 and after some heavy googling I'm still stuck with user input validation.

What I'm trying to do is correct user input on the fly. User is to input a phone number and digits should be corrected (using libphonenumber library) as he types.

Solutions I found on the net don't seem to work for a *8.1 universal project* (or is it just my bad?):

- `PreviewTextInput` or `PreviewKeyDown` events are not available
- `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute` is not available
- `System.Windows.Data.Binding.ValidationRules` is not available

Below is what I currently do. Doesn't seem right to me, and sometimes you can briefly see input before it gets corrected. What is the correct way?

```
void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
  TextBox box = sender as TextBox;
  int caret = box.SelectionStart;
  // sometimes input is briefly visible before it gets corrected
  box.Text = SomeLogic(box.Text);
  box.Select(caret, 0);
}
```

---

**Update:** Alright, this is ugly (ad-hoc, non-declarative, inflexible), but it works. Is this really the way?
With all the power and the might of XAML... Srsly?

```
void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if(!IsNumber(e.Key)) {
    e.Handled = true;
  }
}

List<VirtualKey> NumericKeys = new List<VirtualKey>{
    VirtualKey.Number0,VirtualKey.Number1,VirtualKey.Number2,VirtualKey.Number3,VirtualKey.Number4,
    VirtualKey.Number5,VirtualKey.Number6,VirtualKey.Number7,VirtualKey.Number8,VirtualKey.Number9,
    VirtualKey.NumberPad0,VirtualKey.NumberPad1,VirtualKey.NumberPad2,VirtualKey.NumberPad3,VirtualKey.NumberPad4,
    VirtualKey.NumberPad5,VirtualKey.NumberPad6,VirtualKey.NumberPad7,VirtualKey.NumberPad8,VirtualKey.NumberPad9
  };

public static bool IsNumber(VirtualKey key)
{
  return NumericKeys.IndexOf(key) >= 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a thought- textbox's KeyDown event gets triggered before TextChanged, maybe try putting your logic there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only ways to handle live validation in a TextBox is to handle TextChanged.

Key events will work only if the app is validating keys (rather than characters) and--more importantly--if the input comes through the keyboard. Key events won't catch pasted data, ink or speech recognition, IMEs, etc.

Depending on the nature of the input you may want to auto-correct or you may want to display an invalid-entry message next to the field, and you may want to block committing the value until it is valid.

Be careful not to auto-correct invalid entries that are on the way to valid entries. This is less important when you have a stand-alone field rather than several that depend on each other. It can be really frustrating if two fields depend on each other and require that they be changed in the right order.

You are correct that there aren't any high-level validation systems in-box. I believe there are several third party versions and it's not hard to build a validating control yourself to your own specifications.

You can request and vote on new features at the Windows Platform Dev feedback site at http://wpdev.uservoice.com

Comment: Okay, got it, thanks for elaborate answer. What a shame we have to resort to this low level stuff while the whole idea of having a declarative UI system is to spare you the burden.

Answer (score 0):

KeyDown is the one you need. And you've got it.

But does it work if you press a key and keep it pressed?

Also, try KeyPress().

Comment: I wanted something clean. The declarative way. Blocking keys is just plain stupid and not flexible. Can't believe this is the way to go, but can't seem to find something that works either. :(